# Extend a function to all polynomials ( just 2 variables) when one knows its values on monomials

Tags: performance-tuning

I need your help to make my code faster.

I have a formula for computing a value from any monomial $x^i y^j$, say `formular1[i_,j_]:=(Gamma[i]/Gamm[j] )`. It is just an example, anyway.

My task is to extend this function to all polynomials `f[x,y]`, as fast as possible.

One approach is to use `CoefficientList` to get a matrix of the coefficients of `f[x,y]`. Next, using `Table[Table[...]...]` to construct a matrix whose entries is the values of `formular1[i,j]`; Then multiply (entry by entry, not matrix multiplication) these 2 matrices and find the total of its entries.

This approach is slow when my polynomial is of high degree but sparse.

I once tried another approach:

Define

```
MonomialValue[c_ x^(i_) y^(j_)]:= c * formular1[i,j]
MonomialValue[x^(i_) y^(j_)]:= 1 * formular1[i,j]
MonomialValue[c_ x^(i_)]:= c * formular1[i,0]
MonomialValue[x^(i_)]:= 1 * formular1[i,0]
....
....
```

Then

```
PolynomialValue[f] :=  Total[MonomialValue /@ MonomialList[ f]]
```

This will avoid the unnecessary computing of `formula[i,j]` when the coefficient of `f[x,y]` is zero, also avoid the unnecessary entries in a huge matrix of coefficient.

The only disadvantage of this second approach is that I have to define `MonomialValue` for all kind of them. I can't not just define `MonomialValue[c_ x^(i_) y^(j_)]`. If I did so, then `MonomialValue[x^2 y^3]` (with coefficient 1) would not be evaluated. In order to make this works for all , I have to defined a total of 16 function.

I need this for just polynomials of 2 variables. But a generalization to several variables is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

As noted by @user565739, my earlier solution does not work when `i` or `j` are unity (because the internal representation of `z^1` does not involve `Power`).  A simple generalization is as follows.

```
f = x^3 y^4 + x^7 y^2;
f /. {z1_^i_ z2_^j_ -> formular1[i, j], z1_ z2_^j_ -> formular1[1, j],
    z1_^i_ z2_ -> formular1[i, 1], z1_ z2_ -> formular1[1, 1]}
```

with answer 2161/3.  Likewise, for `f = x^3 y + x y^2` the answer is `3/2`.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I foget "Replace" and "ReplaceAll"...I used these 2 or 3 times before....

Comment: This doesn't work when f is x^3 y, x^3 y^1, x^3 ...etc. This is the same problem as the second approach in my question.

Comment: @user565739, I have added special cases to accommodate either variable appearing linearly.  Other special cases, like `x^3` also can be added, although your particular choice of `formular1` is singular for terms independent of `y`.

Comment: Although what I really want is a solution that don't need to deal with all the exceptional situations, but you way is still better than my second approach that I mentioned. So I accepted your answer. Thank you.